# Processing - Serial.Write() sending unwanted characters '98'

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I'm controlling an [Arduino Uno](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/uno-rev3) through a [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) sketch using serial over USB.

I have a button in the Processing interface that runs the precoat() method which calls a few other methods and runs a few serial.write() commands.  I think all the relevant code is below.  All the valves are initially set to false.

When I call the precoat method, it should write 58 in setPrecoat() and then 9170 in setPumpSpeed().  Maybe the Arduino sees one string of bytes 589170, but I can handle either fine.  The issue is that for some reason it actually writes 58 **98** 9170.

I can't for the life of me figure out where the 98 is coming from.  If I call the setPrecoat() method and setPumpSpeed() methods separately they both work fine writing 58 and 9170 respectively.  If I adjust the pumpSet from 150 to something else, the 98 is still inserted and the 9170 changes accordingly. Why would a 98 be written?

The only thing that I can think of is that 49 * 2 is 98 and 49 is what I'm adding to *i* to change it from *int 0* to *char 1*, but I can't see how the 49 would make it to Serial output.  Especially considering that myPort.write(98) would actually send a 'b', not '98'.

```coo
void precoat()
{
  autoCount = 0;
  timer = 0;
  setDataLogOn();  // No writing in this method, so I didn't include it
  setPrecoat();
  pumpSet = 150;
  setPumpSpeed(pumpSet);
}

void setPrecoat()
{
  // Sets all modes false and then sets precoat
  // mode to true. Modes are used elsewhere.
  precoatMode = bodyFeedMode = waterRinseMode = airRinseMode = bodyFeedFillMode =
                precoatFillMode = precoatRinseMode = cleanMode = false;
  precoatMode = true;
  valvesRed();   // Draws some red boxes
  stroke(BGPenR, BGPenG, BGPenB);  // Outline color for boxes matches BG
  fill(dataLogGreenR, dataLogGreenG, dataLogGreenB);  // Sets color to green
  rect(0*27+370, 10, 22, 22);                         // Draws one green box
  valveText();  // Prints text on the boxes just drawn
  for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)  // Valve state is a Boolean array which
                             // stores the state of each valve
  {
    if (i == 4 || i == 7)   // Checks 5th and 8th array element.
                            // If false, writes a 5 or 8 which
                            // sets them to true via the Arduino
    {
      if (valveState[i] == false)
      {
        myPort.write(i + '1');  // Edited for clarity i+'1' is more
                                // straightforward than i+49
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (valveState[i] == true)  // Checks other array element. If true,
                                  // writes their corresponding number
                                  // which sets them to false via
                                  // the Arduino
      {
        myPort.write(i + '1');  // Edited for clarity i+'1' is more
                                // straightforward than i+49

      }
    }
  }
}

void setPumpSpeed(int pump)  // Sets the pump speed.  Writing 9 triggers
                             // a method on the arduino which accepts
                             // the next three characters as the
                             // input for a PWM pin.
{
  pumpRed();  // Sets all pump boxes red
  fill(dataLogGreenR, dataLogGreenG, dataLogGreenB);
  stroke(BGPenR, BGPenG, BGPenB);
  if (pump == 30)
  {
    //myPort.write("9031");
    myPort.write('9');
    myPort.write('0');
    myPort.write('3');
    myPort.write('1');
    rect((boxes)*27+370, 10, 35, 22);  // Pump 30 box set to green
  }
  else if (pump == 124)
  {
    //myPort.write("9136");
    myPort.write('9');
    myPort.write('1');
    myPort.write('3');
    myPort.write('6');
    rect((boxes)*27+410, 10, 35, 22);  // Pump 124 box set to green
  }
  else if (pump == 150)
  {
    //myPort.write("9170");
    myPort.write('9');
    myPort.write('1');
    myPort.write('7');
    myPort.write('0');
    rect((boxes)*27+450, 10, 35, 22);  // Pump 150 box set to green
  }
  else
  {
    myPort.write("9000");
    //myPort.write('9');
    //myPort.write('0');
    //myPort.write('0');
    //myPort.write('0');
    rect((boxes)*27+490, 10, 35, 22);  // Pump 0 box set to green
  }
}
```

I implemented i+'1' instead of i+49 in the code. The problem still exists, but it looks cleaner.

Comment: what odes your processing sketch look like? Also, better to send `'1'+i`. Makes more sense IMO

Comment: I think the whole sketch is too large to post here but in a nut shell, there are two threads driven by serialEvent() and mouseClicked().  The arduino sends a data string over once a second which is parsed by serialEvent().  That string contains information such as the state of the valves, the current pump speed, and some readings from sensors.  By clicking on various parts of the UI, you can adjust the positions of the valves.  In the case in question, I click to set the "precoat" mode which is all valves off except 5 and 8 and pumpSpeed 150.  But instead of sending 589170 it sends 58989170.

Comment: You're right that `'1'+i` is clearer.  I'll change my program for clarity but that doesn't seem like it'll solve the issue.

Comment: I asked because it could be the case that you are sending the right thing, but the way you read and output could lead you to think you aren't

Comment: In the arduino I have a serial.available loop which reads the chars as they come in and stores them in a char array.  If it sees values 1-8 it flips the corresponding valve.  If it sees 9 then it takes the next three chars converts them to a 3 digit int and sets the pumpSpeed.  Then once a second it sends a comma separated serial communication for processing to parse which has the pump speed as one of it's items.  So I can see from the pump speed being set at 891 that the arduino received 9891.  Then valve 7 flips which is the rest of the 9170 string.